# Checkboxes filter using jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter, checkbox

I'm trying to make the following code work, but my jQuery skills are so basic, I can't find the problem

This code is meant to filter a list based on arrays of checkboxes

The code is very probably bug free

The problem certainly comes from something stupid like not declaring correctly, not testing in the right conditions or not calling a required script

Thanks a million!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#options input.type_check").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('type_hidden');
            if(!$("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).hasClass('start_hidden')) {
                $("#events li).not(".type_hidden, .start_hidden").slideDown();
            }
        } else {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('type_hidden');
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#options input.start_check").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('start_hidden');
            if(!$("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).hasClass('type_hidden')) {
                $("#events li).not(".type_hidden, .start_hidden").slideDown();    
            }
        } else {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('start_hidden');
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Types:</p>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_0" value="0" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_0">Type 0</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_1" value="1" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_1">Type 1</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_2" value="2" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_2">Type 2</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_3" value="3" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_3">Type 3</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_4" value="4" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_4">Type 4</label></div>

<p>Starts:</p>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_072009" value="072009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_072009">July 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_082009" value="082009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_082009">August 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_092009" value="092009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_092009">September 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_102009" value="102009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_102009">October 2009</label></div>

<p>Events</p>
<ul id="events">
    <li id="a1768" class="type_0 start_072009">Event 1</li>
    <li id="a2190" class="type_1 start_072009">Event 2</li>
    <li id="a2191" class="type_2 start_072009">Event 3</li>
    <li id="a1864" class="type_2 start_082009">Event 4</li>
    <li id="a1679" class="type_3 start_082009">Event 5</li>
    <li id="a2042" class="type_0 start_092009">Event 6</li>
    <li id="a1717" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 7</li>
    <li id="a1917" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 8</li>
    <li id="a1767" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 9</li>
    <li id="a1866" class="type_2 start_102009">Event 10</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this line

```
  $("#events li).not(".t.........
```

Change it:

```
   $("#events li").not(".t
```

Comment: they are 2 lines with this problem, probably from a copy/paste

Comment: Thank Alon.I edited the two lines. Unfortunately, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something to filter results depend on checkbox
check it out
http://jsfiddle.net/ag263ms9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tags">
  <label><input id="ss" type="checkbox" rel="arts" /> Arts </label><label>
  <input id="aa" type="checkbox" rel="computers" /> Computers </label><label>
  <input type="checkbox" rel="health" /> Health </label><label>
  <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" /> Video Games </label>
</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr />
<div id="sso">
  Click to uncheck #Computers</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<hr />
<ul class="results">
  <li class="arts computers">Result 1 </li>
  <li class="video-games">Result 2 </li>
  <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3 </li>
  <li class="arts video-games">Result 4 </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(':checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($(':checkbox:checked').length > 3) {
            alert('you can not check more than 3 checkboxes');
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
}) $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function () {
    var $lis = $('.results > li'),
    $checked = $('input:checked');

    if ($checked.length) {
        var selector = $checked.map(function () {
                return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
            }).get().join('');
        var $results = $lis.hide().filter(selector);

        if ($results.length > 0) {
            $('.no-results-found').remove();
            $results.show();
        } else {
            $('.results').append('<li class="no-results-found">No results found.</li>');
        }
    } else {
        $lis.show();
    }

    //click to uncheck

    $('#sso').on('click', function (ev) {
        $("#aa").prop("checked", false);
        var $results = $lis.show().filter(selector);
    });

});
```